# I would like to implement GRU with LSTM for my own created dataset. Since i am new to python, i am not sure how to add GRU layer. How to add GRU?

Tags: python, recurrent-neural-network

I am getting model_wrapper when the model executes with LSTM. But GRU is not working.

How to execute GRU and LSTM?

```
    #BUILD THE MODEL
        
        top_words = 10000
        embedding_vecor_length = 32
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=X.shape[1]))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(LSTM(100,dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, go_backwards=False))
        #model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        print(model.summary())
        model.summary()
```

how to add GRU with LSTM in the above code?

Is this the correct parameter for adding GRU?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You want to add GRU with LSTM or replace it?

Comment: I want to add GRU with LSTM. I am trying to find the optimization of the models.

Comment: Instead of apologizing about the screenshots, don't put them here. Paste your code as text. If you don't want to spend even few seconds making it easier for someone who would like to help you...

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read, it seems you want to add GRU instead of LSTM. You can just add GRU layer like you did with LSTM

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GRU
model.add(GRU(100,dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
```

If you want LSTM and GRU together (which really depends what you are doing and why you should do it), you need to return sequences from GRU first

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GRU
model.add(GRU(100,dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(100,dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
```

Comment: I wanted to try LSTM and GRU for binary classification labelling. When i tried this code i got this error saying "No module name tf" . Please help how to do this?

Comment: How are you importing LSTM? you need to import in similar way (e.g `from tensorflow.keras.layers import GRU`)

Comment: When i tried this code , the GRU alone is not working instead its displaying module_wrapper in the console. But the LSTM works. I am very new to neural networks please help! Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by `module_wrapper`?

Comment: I have added the screenshot for your reference. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your code, your GRU layer looks okay in terms of output when you print model summary. Are you getting error in fitting? I don't understand exact problem

Comment: When i try to add my full code , its not allowing me to do so. Please how can i share with you?